# Is @WebService annotation a must in service class?

Tags: web-services, soap, cxf

I have a SOAP web service. For experiment, I removed the @WebService annotation in service class and it's still working without any problem. So I think @WebService annotation is not a must in service class. Am i missing something here. ( I'm using CXF 2.7.7 )

Comment: Did you annotate the SEI ?

Comment: Yes. I did annotate the SEI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found This answer from CXF forum. Great place to get help !

http://cxf.547215.n5.nabble.com/Is-WebService-annotation-a-must-in-service-class-td5744739.html#a5744826